# How to make this cartoon look? Photoshop filters

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d, filter

Ok, basically I have 3d renders that I need to make look like concept art, like simple colored vectors that have CLEAN, hard edges like https://dribbble.com/shots/3232637-Hip-hop-dude

I dont want to do this by hand in illustrator as I need a quick solution - just need to basically average the colors in my 3d image so it looks roughly 2d instead of 3d.

With filters I tried:
[image]

However this was too messy, with little "artifacts" not clean edges:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Try with Menu Image > Adjustments > Posterize. But nothing in the quick mode will give you in Photoshop the 2D shapes vector effect. Your 3D program does not have 2D render like Blender?

Comment: @Danielillo It is blender! But Im in cycles and even with freestyle, playing with toon shaders I cant get this desired effect. Never done anything like it.

Comment: This is the same question and a solution: https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15178